# Best method to retry with delay in Java

Tags: java

In my program I call a method that can either return a value or "", and basically I want it to retry looking up the value 3 times with a delay of 1 second inbetween each try until it gets a value or the tries are finished.

This is what I currently have but I feel like this solution is pretty gross, particularly having to put the try/catch around the sleep. Does anyone know of a better way to retry with a delay?

```
public void method(String input){
    String value = getValue(input);

    int tries = 0
    while (value.equals("") && tries < 3){
        try { 
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("Thread interrupted");
        }
        value = getValue(input);
        tries += 1;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty straightforward, except for the fact that you're swallowing the `InterruptedException`. There's a library for these kind of tasks called [retrier](https://github.com/alexo/retrier), but I can't say I've used it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end of the day you can not get around the fact that in needs to catch the Exception

What you can do though is *hide* it by putting in in your own method

```
public static void mySleep (int val) {
    try { 
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(val);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Thread interrupted");
    }
}
```

So you `main` function becomes cleaner as

```
while (value.equals("") && tries < 3){
    mySleep (1);
    value = getValue(input);
    tries += 1;
}
```

Comment: There's also Guava's `Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly()`.

Answer (score 10):

[Fixed Poll Interval](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#fixed-poll-interval) feature of [awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) might help:

```
Awaitility.with()
  .pollInterval(1, SECONDS)
  .atMost(3, SECONDS)
  .await()
  .until(() -> ("" != getValue(input)));
```

It offers a fluent interface for synchronizing asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see anything wrong with using try .. catch.

This is in harmony with the basic philosophy that an exception is not an error - it is just a situation that happens, a way of handling the control flow.

So - I like your solution. I would not change that.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, and basically any solution is going to have that *general* form at its center. If you don't like the verbosity of writing your own retry, check out [Failsafe](https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) and [Guava-Retrying](https://github.com/rholder/guava-retrying), which are libraries to accomplish the same basic thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with Thread.sleep and catching interrupted exception.  The main issue is it will block the thread until it finishes.  To avoid this you'd need some application server level support to allow it [undertow for example](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/creating-a-non-blocking-delay-in-the-undertow-web-server-for-artificial-latency)

```java
    private void sendWithRetry(final InternetAddress[] toAddresses, final Transport transport, final MimeMessage msg) throws MessagingException {

        boolean guard = false;
        for (int retry = 0; !guard && retry < SMTP_RETRY_LIMIT - 1; ++retry) {
            try (final Transport trans = transport) {
                trans.connect();

                // Actually send the message
                trans.sendMessage(msg, toAddresses);

                // Close the connection
                guard = true;
            } catch (final MessagingException me) {
                log.warn("Retry {}", retry, me);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(SMTP_RETRY_DELAY_IN_MS);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    log.warn("Interrupt exception received so interrupting thread and breaking out of retry loop");
                    guard = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!guard) {
            try (final Transport trans = transport) {
                trans.connect();

                // Actually send the message
                trans.sendMessage(msg, toAddresses);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) (added in Java 7) is a good way to implement retries with a delay.

```
 class RetryThreeTimesExample {
   private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
   private ScheduledFuture<?> getValueHandle;

   public void retryForUpToThreeSeconds() {
     final Runnable getValue = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           String value = getValue();
           if (!value.equals("")) getValueHandle.cancel(false);
       }
     };
     getValueHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(getValue, 1, 1, SECONDS);
     scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
       public void run() { getValueHandle.cancel(false); }
     }, 3, SECONDS);
   }
 }
```